# I can't get the rest of the submenu to show properly

Tags: jquery, menu, submenu

I have this menu with a ul submenu and the script i wrote i can only show the first submenu and the other one doesn't show.

this is the jquery script i'm using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#top_menu_blockx').hover(
        function(){
            $('#top_menu_blockx').children('ul').stop().fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function(){
            $('#top_menu_blockx').children('ul').stop().fadeOut('slow');
        }
     );
});
```

I've included a link tot he jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/kakashi807/RrYs4/2/

btw, why the color of the font of the submenu doesn't change to white when the mouse is hovering?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RrYs4/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.top_menu_btnx').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).children('ul').stop().fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function(){
            $(this).children('ul').stop().fadeOut('slow');
        }
     );
});
```

And about your HTML - **ID-s SHOULD BE UNIQUE!**

Answer (score 0):

Try the Same thing by its `ClassName`. Then it will work.

**Fiddle Example :** http://jsfiddle.net/RrYs4/6/

**JQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.top_menu_btnx').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).children('ul').stop().fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function(){
            $(this).children('ul').stop().fadeOut('slow');
        }
     );
});
```